# Authy backup password issue

Tags: authentication, multi-factor

I have enabled Authy backups on my phone, and set the password.

Then I installed the Chrome app on my PC, after I input backup password, the screen shows "Re-encrypting accounts".

When this process finishes, my backup password doesn't work anymore, always saying "Incorrect password".

Also tried to reset backup password from my phone (reset does not work from chrome app), there is the same issue.

Tried to re-install a few times, all the same.

Anybody have a solution?

Comment: I think you should ask this question on the superuser.com, or on apple.stackexchange.com or on android.stackexchange.com .

Comment: This look more like a question for Authy support for the Chrome extension ....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is best answered by the support team of Authy.